# How to save a filtered data from react table to csv using property filterable

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-table

Using filterable property in react table, can we save export the data.
If no values provided to filter, should be able to download default get all records.

tried export-from-json

```
const Export = () => (
  <button 
    className="btn btn-small btn-primary" 
    onClick={() => exportFromJSON({data, fileName, exportType})}>
    Export
  </button>
);
```

Comment: You need to know which filter is applied `onFilteredChange={(filtered, column) => {...}} // Called when a user enters a value into a filter input field or the value passed to the onFiltersChange handler by the Filter option.` there you can filter your array and export it

Comment: Do you have a Sample CodeSandbox in place?